# $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\prod\limits_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ is a topological space and for $\alpha\in I$, $X_\alpha\subset Y$. Then $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\prod\limits_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$.

My main problem in proving this proposition is closedness. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do we have a separation axiom, like $T_1$ assumed on $Y$?

Comment: @Berci: My main goal of this question is show this proposition on metric space $Y$. But i think we can add hausdorffness in space $Y$, since in most papers all spaces considered are assumed to be hausdorff.

Comment: You can suppose $|I| = 2$, the proof is almost the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Then consider the diagonal
$$\Delta_Y:=\{(..,y,y,y,..)_\alpha\,\mid\, y\in Y\}\ \subseteq Y^I$$
It is closed, because whenever $x=(x_\alpha)\notin \Delta_Y$, we have $x_\alpha\ne x_\beta$, so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ around $x_\alpha$ and $x_\beta$, so 
$$x\in Y\times Y\times \dots\times U\times\dots\times V\times\dots\times Y\times Y\times\dots$$
which is open and disjoint from $\Delta_Y$.

So,  we have that $\Delta_Y\,\cap\,\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ is closed in $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ w.r.t. to the subspace topology. And, finally
$$\Delta_Y\,\cap\, \prod_\alpha X_\alpha\ =\ \Delta_{\left(\bigcap_\alpha X_\alpha \right)}
\ \cong\ \bigcap_\alpha X_\alpha\,.$$

Comment: Aren't you assuming the sets $X_\alpha$ are closed? I was wondering about that in my attempt.

Comment: Yes. I thought it was assumed. But not needed. Just updated my answer.

Comment: @Berci: I can't construct a homeomorphism from $\Delta_{\left(\bigcap_\alpha X_\alpha \right)}$ to $\bigcap_\alpha X_\alpha$. please give me more hints.

Comment: @TXC: $\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\rangle\in\Delta_Y\cap\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ iff there is an $x\in\bigcap_\alpha X_\alpha$ such that $x_\alpha=x$ for all $\alpha\in I$. Take your homeomorphism $h$ to be $h(\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\rangle=x$.